# How to set PATH of SGE in cronjob

Tags: shell, cron, sungridengine

My qsub resides in SGE. So while running sh script through cronjob, I am getting error: qsub: command not found.
Currently set path is:
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin

Answer (score 2):

You can set the path or use the full path of `qsub` as @Jens mentioned.

However, this situation typically also means that your login shell is sourcing a file that is setting a bunch of environment variables for you (including `SGE_ROOT`). When your cronjob is run, that file is not being sourced. So in addition to fixing your path (or providing a full path for `qsub`), you also need to find that file, then at the top of your script, you need to source that file (or else go through and manually set each relevant environment variable).

On my system, that file is at `/u/local/etc/profile.d/sge.sh` (so I just put `. /u/local/etc/profile.d/sge.sh` at the top of my script), but the location of the file varies from setup to setup. You just need to hunt down which file is setting `SGE_ROOT` when you log in (as well as the several other relevant environment variables such as `SGE_ARCH`).

(If you have a particularly hard time finding which file it is, you may find this answer useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154971/157777.)

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the `PATH` at the beginning of the script, e.g. with

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH):/some/other/dir:/yet/another/dir
...rest of script...
```

or modify the crontab entry to provide an augmented initial `PATH` with

```
10 20 * * * PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/some/other/dir:/yet/another/dir /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: I set PATH as per your suggestion, but it gives me error: Please set the environment variable SGE_ROOT. When I am setting this variable, it gives me error related to that path though I gave correct path.

Comment: @Dharmendra Maybe that variable needs to be exported? Use `SGE_ROOT=... ; export PATH SGE_ROOT` in your script at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

After you add the full `PATH` of `qsub`
you can find the `SGE_ROOT` and add it to `crontab`

Write in `crontab` like this:

```
SGE_ROOT=<root_name>
PATH= xxxxxxxx
```